# Apache Artemis Master-Slave Configuration: RAM consumption increases continuously up to 100% RAM usage - after that Broker stops working

Tags: java, mqtt, activemq-artemis

I have a problem with the artemis failover cluster (master-slave configuration) and do not find an answer what I am doing wrong.

My systems are two Ubuntu Linux 18 VM's with 4 Cores, 16GB RAM and 120 GB SSD and I use apache-artemis-2.11.0 with java version 1.8.0_111. I configured "-Xmx14G" in the artemis.profile file to give the artemis enough memory to run.

```
JAVA_ARGS=" -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms512M -Xmx14G -Dhawtio.realm=activemq  -Dhawtio.offline=true -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal -Djolokia.policyLocation=${ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI}jolokia-access.xml"
```

The master - slave behaviour is as expected and works good (also with retain messages), as well the publish and subscribe via tls certificates or basic authentication.

The problem is, that we transmit a lot of messages (5000) to round about 700 topic/queue per seconds and after some time (12-15h) the ram usage of the artemis master vm is 100% and the artemis master refuses any new connections. (...the slave only have about 800MB RAM usage) If I shut down the master manually, the slave jumps in.

I tried to configure the size of each queue/topic with max-size-bytes parameter and global-max-size parameter, but I do no get a better behaviour of the system.

This is my address setting:

```
          <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>           
            <max-size-bytes>204800</max-size-bytes> 
            <page-size-bytes>102400</page-size-bytes> 
            <page-max-cache-size>1</page-max-cache-size>  
            <default-last-value-queue>true</default-last-value-queue> 
            <default-last-value-key>_AMQ_LVQ_NAME</default-last-value-key>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
            <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>            
         </address-setting>

...

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>
```

The global-max-size is 1/5 of the java heap memory size:  (https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/perf-tuning.html    --> Tuning the VM)

`<global-max-size>3006477107</global-max-size>`

Our replication mode (master) is:

```
<ha-policy>
    <replication>
       <master>
               <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
       </master>
    </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

Currently I do not know what's the problem. Do anyone know what we/I did wrong?

Comment: What protocols are your clients using? Are your consumers keeping up with the producers? If not, why not? Have you captured a heap dump when you run out of memory? If so, did you analyze it? If so, where was most of the accumulation? Are you using replication or shared storage for HA?

Comment: Is master/slave required to reproduce the issue or does it happen with just a single broker? When you say the "master refuses any new connections" what do you mean exactly? Do you get any errors/exceptions in the log?

Comment: - the clients use the mqtt protocol
- we use replication setting (I added the config to my post)

Comment: - no, we do not capture a heap dump

Comment: ""master refuses any new connections" what do you mean exactly?"  --> I mean that no connection to the artemis broker is possible. the artemis java process on master is running and working as "live or master broker" but the RAM usage is 100% also the CPU usage of the 4 Core is at a very high value

Comment: "Do you get any errors/exceptions in the log?"  --> no unfortunately not

Comment: btw. we do not get a OutOfMemory exception

Comment: For now I decided to update the artemis to the current version 2.14. and the latest java jdk and it seems that artemis run better. So I think we can close this discussion.

Comment: If you run into this kind of situation again collect multiple thread dumps and a heap dump. That will greatly help in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: okay justin, i will do so. thank you